# Xamarin.Forms configuration of specific page orientation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, orientation

Tried to find orientation settings or configuration properties but didn't find.
And there is a question:

Is it possible to disable changing orientation on some specific page ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is possible, but will require a lot of extra custom renderer work: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18251/prevent-screen-rotation

For Android, you'll probably have to set the `Activity.RequestedOrientation` to `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR` when you don't want rotation, and to `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR` when you do want rotation.

The iOS solution is linked in that thread, and involves using a custom renderer.

Hope that helps!